# list out of range. Loop list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

Can you please help me with my problem ? in line 28 says list index out of range.
I tried change for i in list to for i in range(len(message)) but it didn't help.
Thanks for help

```
letter = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
    'r', 's', 't','u', 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z',
]

falseletters = [
    'r', 's', 't','u', 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
]


message = [

]
def writing():
    print("start writing")
    print("write ,,end'' to end")
    x = True
    while x:
        b = input(">>")
        if b == 'end':
            x = False
            nour = 0
            for i in range(len(message)):
                nour = nour + 1
                check = message[nour]
                if check in [falseletters]:
                    print(falseletters[nour])
                if check not in [falseletters]:
                    print(check)

        if b != 'end':
            message.append(b)
            print("added", b)
writing()
```

Comment: You have never used `i`, so it is useless to change `for i in list` to `for i in range(len(list))`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to find the problem yourself first before posting. Also, please do not use irrelevant tags for your question. Only tag an IDE if you have a good reason to believe that the IDE is involved in causing the problem, or if your question is about using the IDE.

Comment: I think it's because your list of `message` is empty and you are taking `for i in range(0)`

Comment: Also, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting as multi-line code. We should not have to figure out for ourselves which line is line 28. (Do not add line numbers to the code.) The error message shows a lot of useful information. (You should also read it, and try to understand it, as part of the "try to find the problem yourself first" step.)

Comment: @debugger no, that does not cause an error.

Comment: the lists `letter` and `falseletters` are the same

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah I tried to compile his code  online and it's running well. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you give us an exemple of the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

There's several errors in your code: however, the core of your problem I believe lies in the fact that you're not iterating over each letter over each word in the `message` list, rather you're checking if any of the words is in `falseletters`. Here's a working example of what I believe you're trying to accomplish:

```py
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

falseletters = "rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq"


def mapper(letter: str) -> str:
    return falseletters[letters.index(letter)]


message = []


def writing():
    print("start writing")
    print("write ,,end'' to end")
    x = True
    while x:
        b = input(">>")
        if b == "end":
            x = False
            for check in message:
                print("".join(map(mapper, check)))

        else:
            message.append(b)
            print("added", b)


writing()
```

It takes each word in `message`, and maps each letter of the word to the false letter. Then, each mapped character is printed as a string.